# escape curly brackets in templates

Tags: go

How do I escape curly brackets in golangs template system?
Assume I want to print `{{Hello World}}`:

```
var buf bytes.Buffer
// tpl := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(`{{ print "{{Hello World}}"}}`)) // this is working
tpl := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(`\{\{Hello World\}\}`)) // this is not
if err := tpl.Execute(&buf, nil); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
if buf.String() != "{{Hello World}}" {
    panic("Unexpected")
}
```

[go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/PlNKWTOhFeY)

Comment: Use a string literal: `{{ "{{Hello World}}" }}`

Comment: You don't need the `print`, printing is what templates do - you can just use `{{ "{{Hello world}}" }}`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use a raw string constant.

```
tpl := template.Must(template.New("").Parse("{{`{{Hello World}}`}}"))
```

https://play.golang.org/p/FmPo6uMUBp8

Comment: This really only works for single-line strings or strings that are programmatically generated. Most of the time if you're dealing with a template literal, you'll need to use Go's `\`` string syntax which doesn't allow for `\`` marks in the string itself. :/